# HTML Ordered List as the following 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.1, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1.1

Tags: html, html-lists

Can you please help me to create an ordered list which has the top most list items ordered as 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 etc.

Here is the existing fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/PTbGc/632/

The list css i am using is

`OL { counter-reset: item; padding-left: 10px; }
 LI { display: block; }
 LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }`

The sub lists are ordering correctly. I just want to make the top lists end in .0

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8jrxh76/2/), I managed to get what you wanted by using a single counter before counters.

Edit: Since there are a lot of people which prefer classes over direct html tags (including me) I created [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8ms8rkz/15/) that shows the concept with css classes. The best solution would be to mix both techniques together [like in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amfeya71/2/), this is the way I would use.

The css is

```
/* selector for the first level of the nested list */
BODY > OL {
  /* reset the item counter when a new nested list starts
     e.g. everytime there is a <ol> tag as a direct child of the <body> */
  counter-reset: item;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

/* selector for the list items on the first level */
BODY > OL > LI::before {
  /* prepend X.0 to the content of every list item that is a direct 
     child of <ol> which is a direct child of the <body> */
  content: counter(item) ".0 ";
  counter-increment: item
}

/* selector for all sublists */
LI > OL {
  padding-left: 10px;
  /* when entering a new sublist reset the subitem counter */
  counter-reset: subitem;
}

/* selector for the items of in every sublist */
LI > OL > LI::before {
  /* prepend the current value of the item counter and the subitem
     counters to the content of each <li> tag in a sublist. */
  content: counter(item) "." counters(subitem, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: subitem
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see this works perfectly on the fiddle. Could you help me to understand? Unfortunately on my page, inside the body tags, i get http://prntscr.com/ig2in1 and where I need it in the page (inside two more div's) I get http://prntscr.com/ig2j7r

If i set the ol inside the body to list-style-type: none then i loose the leading numbers, but they remain for the list items.

Comment: Actually I got it to work using your code, I just had to create a class to use for the ol, and attach the css to the class. This made it target the specific list rather than be affected by where it was on the page. After that it worked.

Comment: I'm happy you got it working. I edited my answer a little to make the things a clearer.